# How do i looping through my recordset using an array?

Tags: arrays, loops, ms-access, vba, record-count

I would like my function to open the table, and return 1/1/2013 for recordcount 1, 1/2/2013 for recordcount 2 ... 1/20/2013 for record count 20.

so far I have the following code but it only return 1/2/2013 and I have 24 records:
(My recordcount will vary from 22 -30 each month)

```
Public Function DDate() As Date

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim icounter As Integer
Dim UpBound As Long


Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblDDate", dbOpenDynaset)


    If Not (rst.BOF And rst.EOF) Then
        rst.MoveFirst

        UpBound = rs.RecordCount

    Do Until rs.EOF = True

        For icounter = 1 To UpBound
            DDate = DateAdd("m", icounter, "1/1/2013")
            rst.MoveNext
        Next icounter
    Loop
    End If

rs.Close
db.Close

 End Function
```

Comment: What does your table structure look like? Are you trying to loop through fields or do you just want to loop through rows? Do you have a Date field in tblDDate that you could group on using a GROUP BY statement?

Comment: My table does not contain date, I am trying to add a date field to this table. I would like to loop through the rows. The field count will always be the same. so if record/row 1 date = 1/1/2013 if record/row 2 date = 1/2/2013. Instead of doing 30 if statement, I am trying to loop through the recordset. thanks

Comment: Your reply doesn't make sense to me. How do you know that Record1 has a date of 1/1/2013 if you don't have any date field?

Comment: I may not be doing this right, I may have to go back to doing this in a query as John suggested. What I am trying to do is create a new field. Once the field is there, Loop through the table, then for each record add 1 to the first day of the month. The table have several other fields in it including an ID field. What I had before I tried to do this in a function was a make table query with a very long equation that did not always work because the # of record change each month.

Comment: In the make table query I had, DDate: iif(ID = 1, 1/1/2013, iif(ID = 2, 1/2/2013, iif(ID = 3, 1/3/2013....))). I figure there must be a way to do this each month without going in and changing this manually.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment above says that the table doesnt contain a date but that you are trying to add a date field to the table.

Unfortunately you cannot add a new field (column) to a table like this. You'll need to do that either in design view, or running an ALTER statement on the database at runtime:

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName ADD COLUMN dateColumnName Date Null;
```

then if you want to set the value of the column, hopefully your table has a unique id with the datatype counter(?) I'd recommend you to use an update query:

```
UPDATE myTableName SET dateColumnName = CDate("1/" & trim(uniqueIDColumnName) & "/2013");
```

Comment: Thanks John, That is exactly what I am trying to do. My records does have unique IDs. Will give this a try tomorrow.